# padding-right in a 100%width div

Tags: html, css

I have a very basic CSS question, with following markup:

```
#content_container {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
  min-height: 800px;
  margin: 10px auto 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

and inside this div I have a few boxes:

```
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 378px;
  background-color: #F2EBE0;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

due to the `float`, the boxes break when I resize the browser window. This works quite good.
But what I know want to do is keep `150px` space on the right side of the div. So I'm trying to add `padding-left: 150px` to `#content_container`. But instead that the div is behaving like before, it gives me a x-scrollbar and gets added the 150px to that.

My question is, how can I add the padding within the 100% width of the browser.
To explain the problem better I made an [Image](http://super-sized.de/explain.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with using 
 
`* { 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
   box-sizing: border-box; 
}`

Comment: yep that was it. Can you explain what it exactly does since I've heard of this property the first time.

Comment: [here](http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/box_sizing/) and [here](http://learnlayout.com/box-sizing.html) you can find the explanation with a practical example ;)

Comment: your welcome ;) btw, don't forget to flag the answer if you solved your issue